# Form given padding-right even though padding is 0px

Tags: css, html, pug, stylus

No where in the code is a right margin or right padding set, and when viewing the form element in Chrome's developer tools, it shows both "padding: 0" and "margin: 0" in the Styles listing, but *does* show a margin when hovering over the form element. [image: Padding being shown]

The Stylus CSS code is as follows:

```
.barFive
  background-color dark-blue

  form
    width(800px)

    .label
      display table-cell
      padding 20px

      .sec
        display inline-block
        vertical-align middle

      .message
        width(150px)
        text-align right
        padding-right 20px

        font-family Helvetica
        font-size 1.6em
        color white

      input, textarea
        padding 10px
        width(500px)

        font-family Helvetica
        font-size 1.6em
        color darken(dark-blue, 40%)
        background-color light-blue

        border-radius 5px
        border 1px solid light-blue
```

The Jade code is this, with more div.label elements ommitted.

```
  +sub-bar().barFive

    +title("Contact", "Ask Us Anything")

    form
      div.label
          div.sec.message
            span Name
          div.sec.input
            input(type="text" name="Name")
      br
```

+sub-bar() and +title(x, y) are mixins that are defined as follows:

```
mixin sub-bar()
    div.sub-bar(class!=attributes.class)
        div.container
            if block
                block
            else
                +error("No content provided")

mixin title(x, y)
    div.title
        h1.sub.main #{x}
        h3.sub.subtitle  #{y}
```

Comment: Post a Jsfiddle link of this please

Comment: You have set your form to exactly 800px wide. Why do you think there is extra padding? That orange section shows the remaining space inside the element's container, not padding. padding is shown green if I recall correctly.

Comment: As @JesseKernaghan said, if your div parent haves a bigger width than the form, the form will show "margin right" when you haven't set it (beign not margin). If you want to ocupate all the div parent, put the form width to 100%, or if you want your form centered to that div, put a `margin: auto;`

Comment: Actually I just realized orange represents margin. In the Computed tab it is showing orange as margin.

Comment: Chesire. Your answer helped me a lot. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it. Especially the part about centering, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your form is 800px wide which is correct (that's what the debugger says). Actually there's a padding-right on your message class 20px and, not a problem here since there's a bigger padding on the message class but still, 10px padding all around your inputs.

Comment: Increasing the width() of the form lessens the orange area. Decreasing the width increases the orange area. And adding box-sizing changed nothing. Also, the padding on the message class effects the words next to the input.

Comment: the right orange section is not padding, but width difference with the parent. Try to make the form width:100% and i suspect it will disappear.

Comment: so the 'message' is 150px wide and the inputs/textarea are 500px width. If your form is 800px wide, the orange color that is 150px represents the empty space... which is not a padding but just a substraction xD

Comment: By the way, you can remove your padding-right on the span. Unless you set it to display: block, span doesn't get affected by padding :)